# Stop dark mode from destroying my CSS on Samsung internet browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a website with CSS styling. When I view in certain Samsung internet browsers when dark mode is enabled the CSS is absolutely destroyed and the logo, header and footer which have changed in my site look absolutely bad. How can I prevent my CSS, color schemes being changed because of dark mode

When I opened my URL android device from the internet Samsung browser - automatically restyles the CSS because I have dark mode active. If other users go to my page and have dark mode active I would prefer them to see the original styling not the dark mode edited version

Comment: Do you mean samsungs browsers automatically generates a dark mode for you or that your implemented dark mode displays incorrectly on samsungs built-in browser?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.